# ¿Como hacer un JOIN con Criteria API?

Tags: java, jpa, primefaces, criteria-api, eclipselink

quiero implementar la carga perezosa de registros en un DataTable de Primefaces (versión 7). Tengo dos entidades, una se llama Facultades y la otra Carreras, las cuales se encuentran relacionadas. El datatable muestra correctamente el listado de todas las carreras (incluye paginación y filtrado), el problema que tengo es que no se como filtrar las carreras por el nombre de una determinada facultad, ya que no se como incluir el join en la consulta que dejo a continuacion.

¿Podrian orientarme sobre como resolverlo por favor?

Entidad Facultades

```
public class Facultades implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idfacultad")
private Integer idfacultad;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "abreviatura")
private String abreviatura;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idfacultad")
private List<Carreras> carrerasList;}
```

Entidad Carreras:

```
public class Carreras implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idcarrera")
private Integer idcarrera;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 150)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "tipo")
private int tipo;
@JoinColumn(name = "idfacultad", referencedColumnName = "idfacultad")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Facultades idfacultad;}
```

Query

```
public List<Carreras> findByParams(int start, int size, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Carreras> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Carreras.class);
    Root<Carreras> root = criteriaQuery.from(Carreras.class);
    CriteriaQuery<Carreras> select = criteriaQuery.select(root);

    Join<Carreras, Facultades> facultad = root.join("idfacultad");

    if (sortField != null) {
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(sortOrder == SortOrder.DESCENDING ? criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(sortField)) : criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(sortField)));
    }

    if (filters != null && filters.size() > 0) {
        List<Predicate> predicados = new ArrayList<>();

        filters.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object val = entry.getValue();
            if (!(val == null)) {
                // Construimos la expresion con los predicados que si existan
                Expression<String> expresion = root.get(key).as(String.class);
                Predicate predicado = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(expresion), "%" + val.toString().toLowerCase() + "%");
                predicados.add(predicado);
            }
        });
        if (predicados.size() > 0) {
            criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicados.toArray(new Predicate[predicados.size()])));
        }
    }
    // Creamos la consulta
    TypedQuery<Carreras> consulta = em.createQuery(select);
    consulta.setFirstResult(start);
    consulta.setMaxResults(size);

    return consulta.getResultList();

}
```

Datatable de primefaces
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Después de tanto probar y equivocarme encontré una solución que funciona y devuelve los valores que esperaba. Seguramente este código se puede mejorar. Lo dejo por si alguien esta en una situación similar a la mía y lo necesita.

```
private static void listarCarreras(String nombreCarrera, String nombreFacultad) {
        try {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("consultasPU");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Carreras> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Carreras.class);

            Root<Carreras> raiz = criteriaQuery.from(Carreras.class);
            Join<Carreras, Facultades> joinFacultad = raiz.join("idfacultad", JoinType.INNER);

            List<Predicate> listaPredicados = new ArrayList<>();

            criteriaQuery.select(raiz);

            if (!nombreCarrera.equals("")) {
                Predicate predicadoNombre = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(raiz.get("nombre")), "%" + nombreCarrera.toLowerCase() + "%");
                listaPredicados.add(predicadoNombre);
            }

            if (!nombreFacultad.equals("")) {
                Predicate predicadoFacultad = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(joinFacultad.get("nombre")), "%" + nombreFacultad.toLowerCase() + "%");
                listaPredicados.add(predicadoFacultad);
            }

            if (listaPredicados.size() > 0) {
                listaPredicados.forEach((p) -> {
                    System.out.println("Predicado : " + p.getExpressions().toString());
                    criteriaQuery.where(listaPredicados.toArray(new Predicate[listaPredicados.size()]));
                });
            }

            TypedQuery<Carreras> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(10);

            List<Carreras> lstCarreras = query.getResultList();

            lstCarreras.forEach(p -> {
                System.out.println(p.getNombre() + " - " + p.getIdfacultad().getNombre());
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No hay nada..." + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```